# How to change a value in Pandas Data Frame after adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a DF when I have loaded the dataset. After that, I need to add a new column and assign values based on a condition. When I add it, I can not change the Value.

P.S. I saw and test a lot of answers in SO. I have attached the picture and code:

```
counter = 0
for checkin in df.itertuples():

   counter += 1

   if isWeekday(checkin[2]):
       print(isWeekday(checkin[2]))
       df['weekday'] = 100
   else:
       print(isWeekday(checkin[2]))
       # df['weekday'].replace(0)
       # df[checkin[0]]['weekday'] = 10
       # df.assign(weekday = 0)

   if counter == 10:
       print(df.head(10))
       break
```

[image]

> I need to change the `weekday` value to 0 in the else section (when the condition is FALSE).

Comment: None of the commented codes do work!

Comment: Please provide example data with desired output - [mcve]

Comment: @zipa I need to change the 100 to 0 in the Else section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to completly understand the question, but I think you could

1) Change the data type of checkin_time to a datetime
`df['checkin_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkin_time'])`

2) Create a new column which tells the day of the week
`df['day_of_week'] = df['checkin_time'].dt.dayofweek`

3) Apply whichever condition to extract your weekeday condition

Comment: It has error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'`

Comment: You are right, it should be `dt.dayofweek`, I will correct it right away.

If you prefer a string, you can also use `dt.weekday_name`

Comment: It is good and very fast. I implemented it in a sequential version, and it takes about 8 hours but your idea just takes 1 minutes. How Pandas perform it? Is it a parallel version?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand you want the weekday value to be 100 in if case and 0 in else. Right ?
If that the case, df['weekday'] = 100 will create a new column and update all the values as 100.
Better use indexes to update a individual.

Try something like (as per the comment a small hack) :

```
counter = 0
flag = 0
for checkin in df.itertuples():
   if flag == 0:
      df['weekday'] = 100
      flag = 1

   counter += 1

   if isWeekday(checkin[2]):
       print(isWeekday(checkin[2]))
       df['weekday'][checkin[0]] = 100
   else:
       print(isWeekday(checkin[2]))
       df['weekday'][checkin[0]] = 0

       # df['weekday'].replace(0)
       # df[checkin[0]]['weekday'] = 10
       # df.assign(weekday = 0)

   if counter == 10:
       print(df.head(10))
       break
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that is right. But I do not have the `weekday` column in the loaded dataset. I will add it when I load dataset. How can I do it?

Comment: @SaeedRahmani  hey, i added a temp solution, looking for a better one

Comment: so your solution does not work! and the problem exists!

Comment: @SaeedRahmani  its very basic nothing fancy, simple logic when flag is zero which will be during first iteration it creates a new column and adds 100 to all the rows as value and updates the value of flag, next time it won't go inside....... can you post how are you implementation

Comment: @SaeedRahmani  check this out....new = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3]], columns=['A','B'])

Comment: @SaeedRahmani   i = 0
flag = 0
for checking in new.itertuples():
    if flag == 0:
        new['C'] = 100
        flag += 1
        
    if i == 0:
        new['C'][checking[0]] = 100
    else:
        new['C'][checking[0]] = 0
    i+=1